# google or-tools can not get to optimal LP result as in gurobi example

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, or-tools

I'm trying to solve a problem from classic mathematical programming book by P.Williams using OR-Tools by Google. The same example is used in Gurobi demo: http://www.gurobi.com/resources/examples/food-manufacture-I

My solution is close to optimal but doesn't match the answer from Gurobi sample(actually that is the one stated as correct in the book as well).

I checked OR-tools solution against constraints, everything looks correct but it doesn't match the optimal answer.

Am I doing something wrong, or it's because of any limitation of OR-tools GLOP algorithm comparing to Gurobi.

The link to my code of GitHub: https://github.com/APA092/optimum_global/blob/master/food_produce.py

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

def main():
    data = [[110, 120, 130, 110, 115],
            [130, 130, 110, 90, 115],
            [110, 140, 130, 100, 95],
            [120, 110, 120, 120, 125],
            [100, 120, 150, 110, 105],
            [90, 100, 140, 80, 135]
        ];

    char = [8.8, 6.1, 2, 4.2, 5];

    solver = pywraplp.Solver('Linear_test', pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)

#create variables
    buy = [[0 for x in range(len(data[0]))] for y in range(len(data))] 
    produce = [[0 for x in range(len(data[0]))] for y in range(len(data))] 
    store = [[0 for x in range(len(data[0]))] for y in range(len(data))] 

    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        for j in range(0, len(data[0])):
            buy[i][j] = solver.NumVar(0, solver.infinity(), 'buy')
            produce[i][j] = solver.NumVar(0, solver.infinity(), 'produce')
            store[i][j] = solver.NumVar(0, solver.infinity(), 'store')

#create objective
    objective = solver.Objective()
    for i in range(0, len(buy)):
        for j in range(0, len(buy[0])):
            objective.SetCoefficient(buy[i][j], data[i][j]*(-1))
            objective.SetCoefficient(produce[i][j], 150)
            objective.SetCoefficient(store[i][j], -5)
    objective.SetMaximization()

#create constraints
    #production not higher than capacity of machine 1
    constraint1 = [0]*len(produce)
    for i in range(0, 6):
        constraint1[i] = solver.Constraint(0, 200)
        for j in range(0, 2):
            constraint1[i].SetCoefficient(produce[i][j],1)

    #production not higher than capacity of machine 2
    constraint2 = [0]*len(produce)
    for i in range(0, 6):
        constraint2[i] = solver.Constraint(0, 250)
        for j in range(2, 5):
            constraint2[i].SetCoefficient(produce[i][j],1)

    #production not higher than resources available
    constraint3 = [[0 for x in range(len(data[0]))] for y in range(len(data))]
    for i in range(0, len(produce)):
        for j in range(0, len(produce[0])):
            constraint3[i][j] = solver.Constraint(0, solver.infinity())
            constraint3[i][j].SetCoefficient(produce[i][j], -1)
            constraint3[i][j].SetCoefficient(store[i][j], 1)
            constraint3[i][j].SetCoefficient(buy[i][j], 1)

    #storage limited to 1000 units
    constraint4 = [[0 for x in range(len(data[0]))] for y in range(len(data))]        
    for i in range(0, len(produce)):
        for j in range(0, len(produce[0])):    
            constraint4[i][j] = solver.Constraint(0, 1000)
            constraint4[i][j].SetCoefficient(store[i][j], 1)

    #initial storage
    constraint5 = [0]*len(store[0])
    for i in range(0, len(store[0])):
        constraint5[i] = solver.Constraint(500, 500)
        constraint5[i].SetCoefficient(store[0][i],1)
        constraint5[i].SetCoefficient(buy[0][i],-1)
        constraint5[i].SetCoefficient(produce[0][i],1)

    #final storage
    constraint6 = [0]*len(store[0])
    for i in range(0, len(store[0])):
        constraint6[i] = solver.Constraint(500, 500)
        constraint6[i].SetCoefficient(store[4][i],1)
        constraint6[i].SetCoefficient(buy[5][i],1)
        constraint6[i].SetCoefficient(produce[5][i],-1)

    #linking storage and production
    constraint7 = [[0 for x in range(len(data[0]))] for y in range(len(data))]
    for i in range(1,6):
        for j in range(0,len(data[0])):
            constraint7[i][j] = solver.Constraint(0, 0)
            constraint7[i][j].SetCoefficient(store[i-1][j],1)
            constraint7[i][j].SetCoefficient(store[i][j],-1)
            constraint7[i][j].SetCoefficient(buy[i][j],1)
            constraint7[i][j].SetCoefficient(produce[i][j],-1)

    #products characteristics HIGH
    constraint7 = [0]*len(produce)
    for i in range(0, len(produce)):
        constraint7[i] = solver.Constraint(-solver.infinity(), 0)
        for j in range(0, len(produce[0])):
            constraint7[i].SetCoefficient(produce[i][j], char[j]-6)

    #products characteristics LOW
    constraint8 = [0]*len(produce)
    for i in range(0, len(produce)):
        constraint8[i] = solver.Constraint(0, solver.infinity())
        for j in range(0, len(produce[0])):
            constraint8[i].SetCoefficient(produce[i][j], char[j]-3)




    solver.Solve()
    storage_cost = 0
    revenue = 0
    purchase_cost =0

    for i in range(0, len(produce)):
        for j in range(0, len(produce[0])):
            purchase_cost += data[i][j]*buy[i][j].solution_value()
            revenue += 150*produce[i][j].solution_value()
            storage_cost += 5*store[i][j].solution_value()


    profit = revenue - storage_cost - purchase_cost

    print "Profit - " + str(profit)
    print "Revenue - " + str(revenue)
    print "Storage Cost - " + str(storage_cost)
    print "Purchase Cost - " + str(purchase_cost)
```

Comment: It's better if you paste the actual code in the question, rather than a link.

Comment: thank you for advise, added

Comment: I would say it's unlikely that the core-solver is broken as there are a lot of mathematical-safeguards (e.g. from duality theory). On the API-side it's more likely, but probably this is a pure modelling problem. The problem might already complex enough to make manual reasoning troublesome. So i recommend the common thing to do: reduce the problem. The products; the days. Then reasoning about it is much easier. Of course this can render some problem invisible, but then it's maybe some other reduction which can help. Full model debugging is troublesome.

Comment: Another approach is outcommenting a single / or multiple constraint block(s) where you will see, that 2, 3 or even more full constraint/block removals will lead to solutions, which are already lower than your target. It's easy to say then, that the remaining blocks contain *some* problem.

Comment: How different is your answer? Is it within the tolerances of the solver? Another common debugging trick is to add constraints that fix the solution values for some or all of the variables to the values that you expect. Then, if your model is wrong you will get other variables have different values than expected or the model will be infeasible, both of which give you more clues.

Comment: the difference in results is not large but still noticeable. OR-tools optimal result is 106'605, Gurobi and the book show 107'843. I modeled the result from Gurobi solution and looks like their figures are not 100% within case requirements. Not getting too much into details, there is a constraint called hardness, it's required to be <= 6. In Gurobi's solution in several months, it's 6,000244444. That might be the reason(rounding rules(?)). Will drop them an email as a next step.

Comment: Coin LP returns the same solution as Glop.

Comment: Definitely a model issue, I ran GUROBI on the code above, and it returns the same value as Glop.

Comment: everyone, thank you for advice. indeed, there was a mistake in constraint3. fixed and the result is as it has to be

Answer (score 0):

Seems you find that you redefine the `constraint7`.

For the record the patch by the author himself -> https://github.com/APA092/optimum_global/commit/54b15836f5860ab56984ed6d139541e961088159